# drupal add preview button to a specific content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I was looking for a way how to add a preview button to a content type that's missing it and only got the save option.

Preview speeds up the editing process and is especially useful if revisions are used and can prevent unnecessary versions being created just to preview changes.

I'll post my answer for a custom module that worked, there is probably a way also to make the button available to all node / content types.

Answer (score 0):

Custom module: course_preview.module

```
   /**
     * implements hook_form_alter
     * add preview button to content type course_node_form
     * @param $form
     * @param $form_state
     * @param $form_id
     */
    function course_preview_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
    if ($form_id == 'course_node_form') {  // only for course content type

    $form['actions']['preview'] = array(
        '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_DISABLED,
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Preview'),
        '#weight' => 10,
        '#submit' => array('node_form_build_preview'),
      );
        }
    }
```